# Android Loaders onLoadFinished() called immediately

Tags: android, loader, asynctaskloader

I'm implementing network communication using loaders... because most of them recommend it and "they are lifecycle aware".

But in my case I've extended the `AsyncTaskLoader` overridden the `loadInBackground()`  etc.etc. 
And at the end the   `onLoadFinished()` is called normally.

But my problem occurs in case of a network error. If the data is null 
the `onLoadFinished()` is called immediately, without the network call.

As per the google docs:

> In either case, the given callback is associated with the loader, and
>   will be called as the loader state changes. If at the point of call
>   the caller is in its started state, and the requested loader already
>   exists and has generated its data, then callback
>   onLoadFinished(Loader, D) will be called immediately (inside of this
>   function), so you must be prepared for this to happen.

So is this something I've to handle, keep a track using flag and next time call `restartLoader()` in my activity instead of `initLoader()`. Or I'm doing something wrong.

I'm posting important parts of my code below:

> In Main Activity:

```
   protected void postJson(int loaderId, Parcelable object, boolean loadOffline) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(Constants.OBJ, object);
        bundle.putBoolean(Constants.OFFLINE, loadOffline);
        loaderManager.initLoader(loaderId, bundle, this);
    }
```

> NetworkAsyncTaskLoader

```
@Override
public Result loadInBackground() {
                Constants.verbose("loadInBackground Called");
                .....
                Response tempResult;
                try {
                    tempResult = loadFromNetwork();

                   ........
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Constants.error("Network Error for loader Id: " + loaderId, e);
                    return null;
                }
        }



@Override
public void deliverResult(Result result) {
            Constants.verbose("deliverResult called");
            super.deliverResult(result);
        }
```

> `onLoadFinished()` in Activity

```
    @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, NetworkAsyncTaskLoader.Result data) {
        hideProgress();
        Constants.debug("Load finished for: " + loader.getId());
        .....
    }
```

And below is the stack trace..

```
07-31 10:08:02.177 27677-28061/com.sample.test D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to ...
07-31 10:08:02.179 27677-28061/com.sample.test E/Test: Network Error for loader Id: 101
                                                                  java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to ...
07-31 10:08:02.192 27677-27677/com.sample.test V/Test: deliverResult called
07-31 10:08:02.193 27677-27677/com.sample.test D/Test: Load finished for: 101
07-31 10:08:08.982 27677-27677/com.sample.test D/Test: Load finished for: 101
```

As you can see next time I call `initLoader()` or try to initiate network call.. It directly calls `onLoadFinished()`

> **Update:**

Well I ended up by creating a flag which sets to false if there is network error or something goes wrong and then if flag is true call `restartLoader()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you call `deliverResult()` the data is "pushed out" to the `onLoadFinished()` callback method, This is as designed.

If you call `deliverResult(null)` you're basically saying that your results are empty, from the LoaderManager point of view - your Loader finished his job, he "doesn't care" about the null value.

**TL;DR** - Yes, You need to handle the null result yourself and call `restartLoader()` to make your Loader run again.

Comment: No problem. Don't t forget to upvote,  accept the answer. :)